# Django-rest-framework serializer fails to save model instance

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using DRF. 
My models.py:

```
class Farm(models.Model):
    farmer = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Farmer of this farm")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False, verbose_name="Farm name", help_text="Please give a single word name for your farm.")
    address = models.TextField(help_text="Please provide the address without the postal code", blank=False,)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=False, default='12043')
    size = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6, blank=False, )

    #To add user's full name in the admin interface for better readability
    def get_farmer_full_name(self):
        return self.farmer.get_full_name()

    #Works like a verbose_name but for a method 
    get_farmer_full_name.short_description = 'Farmers full name'
```

My serializers.py:

```
class FarmSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
            model = Farm
            fields = ('farmer', 'name', 'address', 'postal_code', 'size')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Farm.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        instance.address = validated_data.get('address', instance.address)
        instance.postal_code = validated_data.get('postal_code', instance.postal_code)
        instance.size = validated_data.get('size', instance.size)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

My views.py:

```
@api_view(('POST',))
def addFarm(request):
    data = JSONParser().parse(request)
    farmer = Farm(farmer = request.user)
    serializer = FarmSerializer(farmer, data=data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

When I hit `url(r'^farms/save/$', views.addFarm),` this url, I want to save a new Farm instance with the parameters provided in request. I am using *Postman* to send the request.

However I get `{"farmer":["This field is required."],"name":["This field is required."],"address":["This field is required."],"size":["This field is required."]}`  error as response.

My request looks like following:

[image]

***Note:*** The first field 'farmer' I can not send as a parameter but I guess I have to extract it with `request.user.id` and pass it exclusively, however I am not sure.

What am I doing wrong? How can this be fixed?

Comment: can you post output of request.data ?

Comment: It looks like this: {u'size': u'123.56', u'postal_code': u'12034', u'name': u'Lisa', u'address': u'lichtenau'} : In postman I selected Raw and Json and passed {
    "name":"Lisa",
    "address":"lichtenau",
    "postal_code": "12034",
    "size": "123.56"
} , for which I got response for Farmer saying this field is required. Also print(serializer.is_valid()) prints False

Comment: if you change this in your view `farmer = Farm(farmer_id = request.user)` to `farmer = Farm(farmer=request.user)` .. is the output the same?

Comment: Ah I forgot to update it in the question, it is already like that. I updated the view in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this in views.py

```
data = {"farmer": request.user.id}
data.update(request.data)
serializer = FarmSerializer(data=data)
```

Or As per your **EDIT**

```
data = JSONParser().parse(request)
data.update({"farmer": request.user.id})
serializer = FarmSerializer(data=data)
```

Comment: That works! Thanks a lot! Is it the standard way of saving the data in DRF? I am relatively new to DRF and earlier I used Forms which turned out to be an useless option for DRF. Can this also be extended to update a farm?

Comment: is_valid function check on declared fields tuple and you were not sending farmer key in the data.

Comment: yes correct! I could use it for updating as well already. Your answer helped a lot.